# membership website codeigniter

Tags: session, web, membership, codeigniter-2

i am newbie here in codeigniter. i was asked to build a-[dooid](http://www.dooid.com)-like-site or a-[aboutme](http://www.about.me)-like-site for my local college so they can make their own identity card. i plan building this website using codeigniter since i heard codeigniter is the most easy to understand and i dont have more than 2 weeks to complete the task.

my questions is :

1. if the dooid build up with codeigniter, how could i make a function
   that allows people choosing their direct url. i mean, if i have a
   class "**User**" and there is a "**show**" method that need
   "**username**" as a parameter. the URL should seems like this one:

   > ```
   >       www.Mysite.com/User/show/<username>
   > ```

   how could they make a their own url like this one:

   > ```
   >       www.Mysite.com/<username>
   > ```
2. i plan to restrict some "method" guest and it will
   be enabled when user login into site. i mean if i have a class
   "**user**" there is a "**edit_profiles**" method. guest can see the
   "**show**" method but logged in users will be able to
   "**edit_profiles**" after login. on the same class.
3. can you tell me how the codeigniter session library class concept? i confused with native session php. is there anybody that can show me some links contains session class tutorial that stores session into databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes this is possible, look into the documentation for custom routes:
   http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html
2. For access control it is simplest to use a prebuilt login library
   such as [ionauth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) or [tankauth](http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) both or which provide the
   features you'll require.
3. The sessions used by CI do not use PHP native sessions. The best guide is in the dosumentation: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html Where the data is stored is determined by the sessions in the config file and is described in the documentation.

Comment: excuse me with my english ..  i am indonesian :D i cant speak english well .. would u like to explain me more about the auth library. which authentication who has the lightweight and easy to understand? i also found AG_auth library .. ?

Comment: oh ya .. is it compatible with Codeigniter 2.1 ?